# Inner loop isn't filling in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

Can any body explain what do I miss in that code ?

Isn't the for-loop not a async processus ?

Why the array keep being empty ?

```
var render = ["Element1","Element2","Element1","Element1","Element1"]

var exhaustive = []

for(var i=0;i<render.length;i++) {

   for(var j = 0;j<exhaustive.length;j++){

      if(!exhaustive[j]===render[i]){

          exhaustive.push(render[i])
      }
   }
}

console.log(exhaustive) // Expected result ["Element1","Element2"]
```

Comment: Your inner loop never runs because `exhaustive.length` is zero when it begins.

Answer (score 3):

`exhaustive.length` is equal to `0`. If `j = 0`, and `0 < 0` is false, then the code in the innermost loop will never run (The conditional part of the for loop must be true for the innermost code to run). `i` will just loop, the inner loop of `j` will be skipped, and then it will exit having done nothing. You can use `console.log` statements inside of the loop to help figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work for the reason [Nicholas explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52673831/2206733). Looks like you're just trying to filter out the unique values from `render` into `exhaustive`. Try this ..

```
exhaustive = [...new Set(render)]
```

Comment: Hmm didn't heard of that . Seems cool

Will take a look right after I manage to understand my initial struggle .

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the inner loop never runs because `exhaustive` is empty. But even if it ran, your code wouldn't work correctly, because you'd call `exhaustive.push()` for every element in `exhaustive` that isn't the same as `render[i]`, but you should only push it once.

You need to do the push *after* the loop, if the loop never found a match.

```js
var render = ["Element1", "Element2", "Element1", "Element1", "Element1"]

var exhaustive = []

for (var i = 0; i < render.length; i++) {
  var found = false;
  for (var j = 0; j < exhaustive.length; j++) {
    if (exhaustive[j] === render[i]) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!found) {
    exhaustive.push(render[i]);
  }
}

console.log(exhaustive) // Expected result ["Element1","Element2"]
```

You can also use the built-in method `indexOf()` to test if the value is already in an array.

```js
var render = ["Element1", "Element2", "Element1", "Element1", "Element1"]

var exhaustive = []

for (var i = 0; i < render.length; i++) {
  if (exhaustive.indexOf(render[i]) == -1) {
    exhaustive.push(render[i]);
  }
}

console.log(exhaustive) // Expected result ["Element1","Element2"]
```

One other thing: use `if (x !== y)` to test if two things are not equal, not `if (!x === y)`

Comment: Ah ah i'm not really familliar with using stack overflow in another maner than in search .

Hope the answer to my question notifiate the right involved persons .

Comment: Isn't  !(x === y)  deeper than !== ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by deeper. `!(x === y)` is the same as `x !== y`. But you left out the parentheses. `!x === y` is equivalent to `(!x) === y` because `!` has higher precedence than `===`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello every body and thank you for all these response and reactivity .

But i still don't get it .

For the Fact that the loops lack width to iterate like Nicholas explained I get it .

```
for (var j = 0; j < exhaustive.length; j++) {
    if (exhaustive[j] === render[i]) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
```

Isn't the break not really necessary for anything but ressources preservations ?

In a strictly logical context in this loop

```
for(var j = 0;j<exhaustive.length;j++){

  if(!exhaustive[j]===render[i]){

      exhaustive.push(render[i])
  }
```

}

For every element of exhaustive, if and only if exhaustive not contain render[i] push render[i]

I don't get why this code adding more than once ?